# The following Function //

Tags: mathematica-online

Would anyone be so kind as to explain the role of the following **//.**, its explanation in the Mathematica documentation centre is often unclear.

Thank you.

JD

Comment: `//` is postfix function application. So e.g. `Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2 // Simplify` is equivalent to `Simplify[Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2]`, which can be convenient when you want to apply a function to the result of a previous expression without the hassle of adding parentheses around the whole expression. The opposite would be `@` for prefix function application. So in summary `f@x == f[x] == x // f` all give the same result, except if operator precedence leads to a different evaluation order.

Comment: Thank you, that was well explained. I think its best I provide some context.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you actually meant `//.`, this would be shorthand infix notation for [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html). When using those shorthand notations, Mathematica code can start to look a bit like Perl ;)

Comment: Don't confuse this postfix function application with `//.` which is shorthand for [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html).  Your quesiton actually has the latter form in **bold** print.

Comment: I find postfix expressions much easier to read, understand and change left to right rather than inside out. e.g.  `a[b[c[1]]]` vs. `1 // c // b // a`.

Answer (score 3):

```
FullForm[expression // function]
(* function[expression] *)
```

`//` is just another way to write functional notation.

Beware that occasionally you may write an expression that contains an operator with less precedence than `//`: in that case to use `//` you'll need to use parentheses around the expression.

Comment: thank you, this is so helpful.

Comment: An example of where parentheses are needed: `f[x] === f@x === (x // f)`